# App that turns the menubar black/dark?

Tags: menu-bar, customization

Is there an app that can change the color of the menubar? I saw one that I'm pretty sure *wasn't* [Nocturne](http://www.blacktree.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MenuBarFilter - "iOS-like dark menu bar for OSX"

http://eece.github.com/MenuBarFilter/

Comment: More up to date fork at http://wez.github.com/MenuBarFilter/.

Answer (score 4):

## [LeoColorBar](http://homepage.mac.com/mdsw/) (Free)

Allows you to change the color of the menu bar.

## [MenuShade](http://www.nullriver.com/products) (Free)

Allows you to dim the menu bar.

[Here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEGdj8kP7pE) a tutorial on changing the menu bar to black.

Answer (score 0):

not an app, but you could use obsidian menubar by Max Rudberg. it's an installer that changes menubar's pngs and substitute  os x's black menubar icons (as well as some 3rd party ones) with white ones. 
see more infos [here](http://macthemes.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=16810834) or download it directly from [Max's website](http://www.maxthemes.com/)